# Using Codesniffer with netbeans for CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans, cakephp-2.x, phpcs

I am using netbeans 8 and CakePHP 2.x. I have installed using composer inside my vendors folder the [codesniffer](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer) for CakePHP.

Then from terminal I run the command:

```
vendors/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendors/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer/
```

Then I am trying to set the phpcs to netbeans.

[image]

On Netbeans output I got the following messages and no valid standards appear to be set:

```
"/usr/bin/php" "/var/www/html/CRM/vendors/bin/phpcs" "-i"
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'DirectoryIterator::__construct(vendors/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in /var/www/html/CRM/vendors/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.php:1995
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/CRM/vendors/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.php(1995): DirectoryIterator->__construct('vendors/cakephp...')
#1 /var/www/html/CRM/vendors/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(926): PHP_CodeSniffer::getInstalledStandards()
#2 /var/www/html/CRM/vendors/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(246): PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->printInstalledStandards()
#3 /var/www/html/CRM/vendors/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(213): PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->processShortArgument('i', 1, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/CRM/vendors/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer/CLI.php(551): PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->getCommandLineValues()
#5 /var/www/html/CRM/vendors/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/scripts/phpcs(37): PHP_CodeSniffer_CLI->process()
#6 {main} in /var/www/html/CRM/vendors/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/CodeSniffer.php on line 1995
Done.
```

But from terminal everything seems to work fine. I run the following command and works:

```
vendors/bin/phpcs --standard=CakePHP app/Controller/
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?